# Replace a value in a file by another one (bash/awk)

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file (a coordinates file for those who know what it is) like following :

```
 1  C       1
 2  C       1     1   1.60000
 3  H       5     1   1.10000     2  109.4700
 4  H       5     1   1.10000     2  109.4700     3  109.4700     1
```

and so on.. My idea is to replace the value "1.60000" in the second line, by other values using a for loop.

I would like the value to start at, lets say 0, and stop at 2.0 for example, with a increment step of 0.05

Here is what I already tried:

```
#! /bin/bash

a=0;

for ((i=0; i<=10 (for example); i++)); do

awk '{if ((NR==2) && ($5=="1.60000")) {($5=a)} print $0 }' file.dat > ${i}_file.dat

a=$((a+0.05))

done
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried a lot of combination for the `{$5=a}` statement but without conclusive results.

Here is what I obtained:

```
 1  C       1
 2  C       1     1 
 3  H       5     1   1.10000     2  109.4700
 4  H       5     1   1.10000     2  109.4700     3  109.4700     1
```

The value 1.6000 simply dissapear or at least replaced by a blank.

Any advice ?

Thanks a lot,
Pierre-Louis

Comment: Welcome to SO, please attach sample output also in your post using code tags.

Comment: Hello @RavinderSingh13, just edited my post :)

Comment: bash does not support floating point arithmetic at all, integers only

Comment: You need to explicitly pass the shell variable to awk: `awk -v "a=$a" ...` -- with that, you have an **awk** variable "a" that has the same value as the **shell** variable "$a"

Answer (score 0):

for this perhaps `sed` is a better alternative

```
$ v=0.00; for((i=0; i<=40; i++)) do 
     sed '2s/1.60/'"$v"'/' file > file_"$i"; 
     v=$(echo "$v + 0.05" | bc | xargs printf "%.2f\n"); 
  done
```

**Explanation**

> > `sed '2s/1.60/'"$v"'/' file` change the value `1.60` on second line with the value of variable `v`
> >
> > floating point arithmetic in bash is hard, this adds `0.05` to the value and formats it (`0.05` instead of `.05`) so that we can use it in the substitution with `sed`.

**Exercise to you**:  in `bash` try to add `0.05` to `0.05` and format the output as `0.10` with leading zero.

Comment: Indeed it worked ! I'm really new about Perl,Sed,Awk... so I don't understand everything yet. could you just explain briefly the last line of your code ? But thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't worry, nobody understands everything!

Answer (score 0):

example with awk *(glenn's suggestion)*

```
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do
    awk -v "i=$i" '
        (FNR==2){ $5=sprintf("%2.1f ",i*0.5); print $0 }
    ' file.dat # > $i_file.dat # uncomment for a file output
done
```

advantage: it's awk who manage floating-point arithmetic